# Rails conventions: deleting unused/empty stylesheet and javascript files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

With the Rails default generators, whenever a controller `foo_controller.rb` is generated the corresponding `foo.css.scss` and `foo.js.coffee` files are created.

**Question**

Sometimes these files are left blank and completely unused. Is there a convention on whether they should be deleted or not?

---

My intuition is that they shouldn't have any impact in production (due to pre-compilation), but they slow down pre-compilation speed (more files to process) and also slow down page loads in development (when the assets are served individually).

Comment: your intuition is correct. You can remove those files.

Comment: Burn them at the stake!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files are created as part of the scaffold but nothing prevents you to remove them. In fact, it may be wise to delete them for several reasons:

- scaffold rules may change and you may need to deal with such files in an upgrade.
- they slow down development real-time compilation
- they may not meet your coding standards
- they are useless

Generally speaking, there's nothing wrong in keeping blank files around. However, they will slowly make your code base less maintainable and more confused.